# Absolute location path for Documents Library in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, rainmeter, windows-libraries

I am using this Rainmeter theme where I need to give the absolute path as a link. I know The Libraries in Windows are not actual folders but virtual paths. But is there a way I can find a location path that points to them?

Comment: could you explain "give the location of the path as a link" a bit better?

Comment: See my answer below. It will be clear to you.

Answer (score 0):

I found it. It seems like I cannot individually access the Pictures or the Music Library. But the path of Libraries as a whole is

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Libraries
```

Edit: Thanks to @akira here is the path of Documents library:

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Libraries\Documents.library-ms
```

Comment: `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Libraries\Pictures.library-ms` does not work?

Answer (score 0):

Piggybacking off of @rockydgeekgod's answer, here are the paths expressed with Windows' `%AppData%` variable:

```
%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Libraries\

%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Libraries\Documents.library-ms
%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Libraries\Music.library-ms
%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Libraries\Pictures.library-ms
%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Libraries\Videos.library-ms
```